# What shaders are in the three.js ShaderLib?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

I see in various demos that you can use a shader like so:

```
shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
```

What other shaders are in ShaderLib, and where is ShaderLib documented? It doesn't even seem to show up in the github repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [r.59](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r59), the three.js shaders available through ShaderLib are:

- basic
- lambert
- phong
- particle_basic
- dashed
- depth
- normal
- normalmap
- cube
- depthRGBA

The shaders in ShaderLib are listed and defined here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r59/src/renderers/WebGLShaders.js#L1936 –
This includes their linked uniforms, as well as included shader shunks, and in a few cases, fragment and vertex shader definitions.

They are so far unmentioned in [the documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/), and for some reason a search in the repo for ShaderLib turns up empty, apparently because of unexplained deficiencies with github search.

Comment: At the time of this question, github search didn't split tokens by punctuation, so a search for "ShaderLib" didn't match "THREE.ShaderLib" :P